# how to add up the values in the flutter list

Tags: flutter, listview

I have a listview as drawn and I want to add up the values that I have marked in red, how do I do that to be able to add the values above.

[image]

and this is the model used in the listview above, and the value you want to add up is the 'sks' value in the model with the INT data type

```
class SumValue {
    SumValue({
        this.status,
        this.code,
        this.data,
    });

    String status;
    String code;
    List<Datum> data;

    factory SumValue.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => SumValue(
        status: json["status"],
        code: json["code"],
        data: List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "status": status,
        "code": code,
        "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Datum {
    Datum({
        this.idTranskripNilai,
        this.idMk,
        this.kodeMk,
        this.nmMk,
        this.sks,
        this.smt,
        this.nilaiAkhirUts,
        this.nilaiHurufUts,
        this.nilaiIndeksUts,
        this.nilaiAkhirUas,
        this.nilaiAkhir,
        this.nilaiHurufAkhir,
        this.nilaiIndeksAkhir,
        this.statusNilaiAkhir,
        this.statusNilaiUts,
        this.updatedBy,
    });

    String idTranskripNilai;
    String idMk;
    dynamic kodeMk;
    String nmMk;
    int sks;
    int smt;
    String nilaiAkhirUts;
    String nilaiHurufUts;
    String nilaiIndeksUts;
    String nilaiAkhirUas;
    String nilaiAkhir;
    String nilaiHurufAkhir;
    String nilaiIndeksAkhir;
    int statusNilaiAkhir;
    int statusNilaiUts;
    String updatedBy;

    factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
        idTranskripNilai: json["id_transkrip_nilai"],
        idMk: json["id_mk"],
        kodeMk: json["kode_mk"],
        nmMk: json["nm_mk"],
        sks: json["sks"],
        smt: json["smt"],
        nilaiAkhirUts: json["nilai_akhir_uts"],
        nilaiHurufUts: json["nilai_huruf_uts"],
        nilaiIndeksUts: json["nilai_indeks_uts"],
        nilaiAkhirUas: json["nilai_akhir_uas"] == null ? null : json["nilai_akhir_uas"],
        nilaiAkhir: json["nilai_akhir"] == null ? null : json["nilai_akhir"],
        nilaiHurufAkhir: json["nilai_huruf_akhir"] == null ? null : json["nilai_huruf_akhir"],
        nilaiIndeksAkhir: json["nilai_indeks_akhir"] == null ? null : json["nilai_indeks_akhir"],
        statusNilaiAkhir: json["status_nilai_akhir"] == null ? null : json["status_nilai_akhir"],
        statusNilaiUts: json["status_nilai_uts"] == null ? null : json["status_nilai_uts"],
        updatedBy: json["updated_by"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id_transkrip_nilai": idTranskripNilai,
        "id_mk": idMk,
        "kode_mk": kodeMk,
        "nm_mk": nmMk,
        "sks": sks,
        "smt": smt,
        "nilai_akhir_uts": nilaiAkhirUts,
        "nilai_huruf_uts": nilaiHurufUts,
        "nilai_indeks_uts": nilaiIndeksUts,
        "nilai_akhir_uas": nilaiAkhirUas == null ? null : nilaiAkhirUas,
        "nilai_akhir": nilaiAkhir == null ? null : nilaiAkhir,
        "nilai_huruf_akhir": nilaiHurufAkhir == null ? null : nilaiHurufAkhir,
        "nilai_indeks_akhir": nilaiIndeksAkhir == null ? null : nilaiIndeksAkhir,
        "status_nilai_akhir": statusNilaiAkhir == null ? null : statusNilaiAkhir,
        "status_nilai_uts": statusNilaiUts == null ? null : statusNilaiUts,
        "updated_by": updatedBy,
    };
}
```

there are some references that I saw but most of them use a list that already has a value for example as below, but what if the data comes from the API

```
void main() {
  List<Data> listData = [
    Data(count: 10, name: 'a'),
    Data(count: 12, name: 'bc'),
    Data(count: 21, name: 'abc'),
  ];

  int sum = listData.fold(0, (int preValue, data) => preValue + data.count);

  print(sum);// 43
}

class Data {
  int count;
  String name;
  Data({required this.count, required this.name});
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, but I tried to sum up the data in the listview API.

Comment: Can you share the _flutter_ code, with the ListView?

Comment: do you want to use it via live share in vs code?

Comment: can you add minimal code where ui is part of this list, if it's future builder, add also future method

Comment: @SayyidJ https://pastebin.com/BSQs4DZ0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import build in collection package :

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
```

map your data from api to new list

```
final listMutu = data.map((e) => int.tryParse(e.nilaiIndeksAkhir ?? '') ?? 0).toList();
```

use `.sum` method to get the sum of collection:

```
return ListTile(
  title: const Text('Total Mutu'),
  subtitle: Text('${listMutu.sum}'),
);
```

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UOmQ7f8XKgMrq00QhT3C1tGR9qTpeh_r/view?usp=sharing

Comment: put it after build() method in the ui

Comment: sorry but the result is not appropriate, the result is 4

Comment: since we dont have the model and api result, try to check or `print(listMutu);` how many item do you get?

Comment: sorry it's appropriate, but I want to add up the 'SKS' but it gives an error
The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.

Comment: ketika saya ubah nilaiIndeksAkhir  menjadi SKS hasilnya 
he argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.

Comment: any Object can to convert to string with '${<Object>}' even if its null

Comment: https://pastebin.com/sA48HY4N

Comment: can you please provide me your model `Data class`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/a2kKtWfM

Comment: sks is int? , so remove int.tryParse(), instead use `final List<int> listSks = data.map((e) => e.sks ?? 0).toList();`

Comment: Voilaaa it worked, thank you I really appreciate for my time and dedication.
i really appreciate you. may God repay your kindness.
Terima Kasih.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250743/discussion-between-sharon-and-sayyid-j).

Comment: i have one more question

Answer (score 1):

you can add another fucntion to your `SumValue` class

```
class SumValue {
 ....
 int get sumCountData => data.fold(0,(int prev, data)=>prev+ data.sks);
```

> you can see full demo here
> https://dartpad.dev/?id=84fc22275a395a86ccc8783ffa319baa

- example how to use it:

```
void main() {
  final exampleJson = {
    'category': 'lorem ipusm',
    'data': [
      {'count': 10, 'name': 'abc'},
      {'count': 10, 'name': 'ab'},
      {'count': 10, 'name': 'a'},
    ]
  };
AnotherData anoterData = AnotherData.fromJson(exampleJson);
  
print(anoterData.sumCountData); // 30
  
}
```